# How to use the PHP-DI Symfony Bridge for Controllers?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4, php-di

I want to use my recently set up Symfony 4 project with PHP-DI 6 and PHP-DI Symfony Bridge 3.

My **project structure** looks like this:

```
|-config
|---dependencies
|-----common.php
...
|-src
...
|-Interop
|---Api
|---Website
|-----Controller
|-------IndexController.php
...
|---Services
|-----Dummy
|-------FooService.php
|-------FooServiceInterface.php
...
|-Kernel.php
```

The classes `FooService` and `BuzService` implement the `FooServiceInterface`.

**`/config/dependencies/common.php`**

```
return [
    IndexController::class => DI\create(IndexController::class),
    FooServiceInterface::class => DI\create(FooService::class),
];
```

The **`IndexController`** gets an instance of the `FooServiceInterface` injected.

```
public function __construct(FooServiceInterface $fooService)
{
    $this->fooService = $fooService;
}
```

The **`Kernel`** extends the `DI\Bridge\Symfony\Kernel` and implements its `buildPHPDIContainer(...)`:

```
protected function buildPHPDIContainer(PhpDiContainerBuilder $builder)
{
    $builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/../config/dependencies/common.php');
    return $builder->build();
}
```

Everythings seems to be set up according to the [PHP-DI Symfony Bridge documentation](http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/symfony2.html).

Everything works fine, if there is only one implementation of the `FooServiceInterface`. But when I add a further one, e.g.:

```
class BuzService implements FooServiceInterface
```

I get an error:

> RuntimeException
>
> Cannot autowire service
>   "App\Interop\Website\Controller\IndexController": argument
>   "$fooService" of method "__construct()" references interface
>   "App\Services\Dummy\FooServiceInterface" but no such service exists.
>   You should maybe alias this interface to one of these existing
>   services: "App\Services\Dummy\BuzService",
>   "App\Services\Dummy\FooService". Did you create a class that
>   implements this interface?

**Why am I getting this error & how to get this structure working correctly?**

Answer (score 2):

This error message looks like a Symfony error message, not a PHP-DI one.

I'm guessing that Symfony scans all your classes for autowiring, including your controller (even though it's not necessary).

This is the first time I hear of this, I guess you need to disable Symfony's autowiring entirely, or for some specific folders? If you can send a pull request to PHP-DI's documentation that would be awesome :)

Comment: Hello Matthieu! Thank you for your answer! Now it's working. There were two places I had to repair in my code: 1. Symfony: In the `services.yaml` at lease one of the following changed had to be made: a. set `services.autoconfigure` (not `service.autowire`) to `false` and/or b. add the path to the `Controller` directory to the `service.App\.exclude` list (or disable the `services.App` at all). 2. PHP-DI: I was using `DI\create(...)` and getting the error "[...] cannot be resolved: Parameter [...] has no value defined or guessable". This call had to be replaced by the `DI\get(...)`.

Comment: I'll send a pull request to PHP-DI's documentation later.